# How to make a WHERE query for Google Charts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I'm playing around with Google Charts and some sample data in Google Sheets. I can draw a basic chart but having issues with doing a WHERE query. Can't really find any good documentation or samples either, strangely enough.

Anyway, trying to do this:

```
    var queryString = encodeURIComponent("SELECT A WHERE B='Mag A', SUM(C) GROUP BY B");

  var query = new google.visualization.Query('dataurl?headers=1&tq=' + queryString);
```

and can't figure out how to write the query to get it right.

The issue can be seen here: https://codepen.io/paperhack/pen/JgbXwN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the syntax should be in order like:

```
"SELECT A,SUM(C) WHERE B='Mag A' GROUP BY A"
```